# Как установить Microsoft Sharepoint Server на Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, sharepoint

Microsoft Sharepoint Server не устанавливается на Windows 10.
При установке требует Server версию Windows, но действия от гугления не помогли.
Как можно установить  Microsoft Sharepoint Server на Windows 10?

Comment: Разве что вручную "пинком" службы и dll-ками в IIS долго и нудно.

Answer (score 0):

Наилучшим решением мне кажется было бы создание виртуальной машины посредством Hyper-V с установкой на нее, к примеру, Windows Server 2012, SharePoint Server и MSSQL Server 2012.